# How to make sure that a Rust attribute proc macro runs before the compiler tries parsing the item?

Tags: rust, macros, rust-macros

I'm trying to make a macro that adds some extra syntax to struct type declarations.
For simplicity, here's a toy example: a macro that replaces "function call"-style type declarations with normal ones.

```rust
#[my_macro]
struct Point {
  x: LiteralType("f32"),
  y: LiteralType("f32"),
}
```

should turn into

```rust
struct Point {
  x: f32,
  y: f32,
}
```

From the output of my code and [`cargo expand`](https://lib.rs/crates/cargo-expand), I can tell that my code produces the correct syntax.
However, before that happens, the compiler has already tried parsing the `LiteralType("f32")` syntax, failed and emitted an error saying as much, and now the whole build fails.

I think I need to somehow force the compiler to run my macro's code to completion before trying to parse it according to the regular Rust rules. I think it might be possible to do using functional macros, because those can accept syntax that's much more unusual, but I'd prefer to stick with attribute macros because those provide a secondary input for attributes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot do that with attribute macros, they always validate their items.

But as you said, you can do that with function-like macros.

Comment: What should I do if I'd like to accept some extra parameters that are separate from the main code body? My first idea is to preprocess the `TokenStream` to find a `Group` at the front, and use the `TokenStream` from there, but I think that might be a bit too surprising for the user.

Comment: @Danya02 I don't understand what you want to do and what you're suggesting.

Comment: I wanted `#[my_macro(some_prop=value, other_prop="other_value")] struct Foo;`, and my thought for how to simulate that is with `my_macro!{ [some_prop=value, other_prop="other_value"] struct Foo; }`. Is there a better way to get that?

Comment: @Danya02 Why can't you use `#[my_macro(some_prop=value, other_prop="other_value")] struct Foo;`? Attribute macros can accept parameters.

Comment: I can't use that because I want to accept my new crazy syntax, which only function-like macros can do. If I were writing a "normal" attribute macro that would have worked.

Comment: @Danya02 Then the best way IMHO will be to emulate the already familiar syntax: `my_crazy_macro! { #[my_macro(some_prop=value, other_prop="other_value")] struct Foo; }`.